# iPhone 4s getting hot

Tags: iphone

I two days ago got a second hand iPhone 4s.
I notice that when I start using it, it becomes hot on top right side (if you look from front) and on left top side (if you look from back) near back camera and side steel too.

It becomes hot and battery also drops quickly like 9-10% in 12-14 mints.

I resetted the network settings too but it didn't solved the problem... :(

Please tell what should I do. I have no SIM card in it!! I'm using without SIM. I just turn on the Wi-Fi for some seconds then this happens.

Comment: Put it on airplane mode and see if this still happens.

Comment: @L.B.   I putted it in airplane mode as you said and I noticed that it still gets hot but a little less. It was little hot while using wifi but it goes more hot on playing a game for just 4-5 minutes....

Comment: Thanks for letting me know :) I thought if it worked I would put it answer form. I know that putting it in airplane mode has helped with battery consumption and heat (for me).

Comment: I think it's the problem in all 4s's not only mine because there are a lot of people trying to find solution for this problem... Is it harmful ?

Comment: I really don't know. Some one who knows more will have to answer that.

Answer (score 1):

Hot while using the phone is almost always a short. You might have it serviced if you think it's a fire risk.

Hot while charging can be a bad charger or a bad battery or a short, so you've got the easier problem to troubleshoot / repair.

Also - the age of these devices mean that the majority will be failing in one way or another whether the batteries need to be replaced or other issues like corrosion or just failure of another component has caused it to be out of design spec.